# distinct listagg in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I have a query something like this:

```
select tab1.id,
(
select listagg(tab2.surna||'  '||tab2.name||':'||tab2.addr||'  '||tab2.numb,',  ') within group( order by tab2.name)
from tab2
where tab1.id=tab2.id2id  /*join tab1 with tab2 */
)as address
from tab1
```

and the result is like:

**name_surname1:addr 1,name_surname1:addr 2,name_surname2:addr 3**

but the exptected result would be something like:

**name_surname1:(addr 1,addr 2),name_surname2:(addr 3)**

how can i implement this in order to avoid duplicate records in the display names?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need 2 levels of `listagg` for that. As you didn't provide any script to replicate your data structure, I provide a generic example of my own...

```
with tab as (
select 's' s,'n' n, 'addr1' addr from dual
union all
select 's' s,'n' n, 'addr2' addr from dual
union all
select 'd' s,'k' n, 'addr3' addr from dual
union all
select 'd' s,'k' n, 'addr4' addr from dual
)
select listagg(res,',') within group (order by res) final_res from ( 
select s || n || ':(' ||listagg( addr,',  ')  within group (order by s,n)  || ')'res  
from tab  
group by s||n
)
```

**result is**

`dk:(addr3,  addr4),sn:(addr1,  addr2)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but now  tab1.id is invalid identifier in this where tab1.id=tab2.id2id clause.I would like tab1.id near final_res attribute but this is not allowed..Any idea?

Comment: @Anastasis - if you want volunteers to help you with your specific table arrangement, you must provide sample input tables in your post.

Comment: Ela @Anastasis , as @mathguy mentions, you are not helping us to help you ;-) however, the idea would be to change your original query a little bit and  to introduce `id2id` to the query given in the solution (let's name it `tab3`)  and then use join `tab1,  tab3 where tab1.id=tab3.id(+)`